# IIS with install4j

Tags: installation, install4j

I want to use Install4j to install my applcation.

I have an application with web service that I want to deploy to inetpub directory and I want also to create IIS applicaiton pool, Website.

Its possible with install4j? If yes, How can I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: How would you do with without install4j? If it involves running executables and modifying the registry, you can do it with install4j actions.

Comment: For now, I just copy the files into wwwroot directory and create the application pool etc... without scripts/automations

Comment: install4j has no specific support for configuring IIS, but in most cases configuration can be automated with the existing actions.